# setid() and getId() methods giving weird results

Tags: android, arrays, runtime

I have this code where I am dynamically adding views and assigning id's by using setId() method. Problem is, when i retrieve the Id's using getId method, I get pretty weird results in the logcat. Below is the code:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    row[i]=new LinearLayout(this);

    items[i]=new AutoCompleteTextView(this);
    items[i].setHint("Enter Item Name");
    items[i].setAdapter(adapter);
    items[i].setThreshold(1);
    items[i].setId(200+i);
    items[i].setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            Log.d("success", String.valueOf(arg1.getId()));
            //quants[arg1.getId()-1000].setText(db.getStockStatus(db.getItemCode(arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString())));
        }
    });
}
```

`logcat` shows me the id as `16908308`. whereas the id should be `(200+i)`.

Comment: try this one `just change arg2 in place of arg1` Log.d("success", String.valueOf(arg2.getId()));

Comment: what are you talking about? arg2 is of the type int. How can you possibly get the id of an int. Moreover arg2 is the position of the item selected. Plz just answer a bit sensibly

Comment: @karansingh have you initialized  AutoCompleteTextView before settign id?

Comment: @Metalhead1247, i did it at the starting of the class and moreover every other method is working just fine on AutoCompleteTextView.

Comment: that means you get position of list see answers also we are saying same thing

Comment: try this trick.String.valueOf(items[position].getId()));

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you do not need get id to play with `AutoCompleteTextView`.

Can you try following code...

```
autoCompleteText.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(arg0.equals(items[0])){
                   //do something with first autoCompleteText
                }else if(arg0.equals(items[1])){
                    //do something with second autoCompleteText
                }else if(arg0.equals(items[2])){
                    //do something with third autoCompleteText
                }else if(arg0.equals(items[3])){
                    //do something with fourth autoCompleteText
                }else if(arg0.equals(items[4])){
                    //do something with fifth autoCompleteText
                }


        }
    });
```

**EDIT**

use arraylist instead of array to avoid duplicate code

```
ArrayList<View> items = new ArrayList<View>();

if (items.indexOf(arg0) != -1) {
AutoCompleteTextView autoText = (AutoCompleteTextView) items.get(items.indexOf(arg0));

// do something with your AutoCompleteText
}
```

Comment: yeah, this can be temporary fix but in future I might write some code which may increase the number of AutoCompleteTextViews as per the user demand. Anyways i will do continue my work by this way.

Comment: Also, since the code for each if statement will be identical, my app will have a lot of redundant lines of code

Comment: look at eidted answer to overcome `lot of redundant lines of code`

Answer (score 0):

```
items[i].setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            // 
            Log.d("success", String.valueOf(position.getId()));

        }
    });
```

please try it..

Comment: plz read my comment and tell me how can you use getId() method on an int type variable

Comment: position is also `int` then how can you get id from it ?

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
items[i].setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            // 
            Log.d("success", String.valueOf(items[position].getId()));

        }
    });
```

Comment: can you print the id what it print?

Answer (score 0):

using this code `items[i].setId(200+i);` you are assigning id to `AutoCompleteTextView`.

And `arg1` in below method is clicked view of `AutoCompleteTextView`(not AutoCompleteTextView)

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int postion,
            long arg3)
```

try this code

```
Log.d("success", String.valueOf(arg0.getId()));
```

Comment: well, this is the problem. If i knew the value of i, i would not need to use the getId() method. I cannot use i because I donot know the value of i.

Comment: use position instead of i.

Comment: 'position' is the position of the item clicked in the list that appears under the autoCompleteTextView. whereas, I want the id of the autoCompleteTextView that was used to click on the item at position 'position'

Comment: I cannot use getId() on getParent(). TRy it your self

Comment: yeh.my mistake..edited ans..now this should work `arg1.getRootView().getId();`

Comment: haha, I tried this the first time and it does not work. Anyways thanx for trying. Atleast you got what i was trying to ask. Scroll down the results and you will see the same dumb answers. lol

Comment: the values you print might be different but try to perform some event using this value.

Comment: wow, and now they start cutting down my repo coz i guess I was being offensive

Answer (score 0):

In your code `onItemClick` you can get `position` of your clicked view.

Now you have to **get value of click view** using

```
String.valueOf(items[position].getId())
```

**update:**

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long arg3) {

            Log.d("val", String.valueOf(items[position].getId()));
        }
    });
```

what is **print in val tag**.

**it will 100% work.**

Comment: 'position' is the position of the item clicked in the list that appears under the autoCompleteTextView. whereas, I want the id of the autoCompleteTextView that was used to click on the item at position 'position'

Comment: as expected, I have 10 autoCompleteTextViews and whenever i click on the item that is at the first position, i get 200 as the id. This means the system is assigning the id using setId() but i am unable to retrieve it back.

Comment: I donot know why the id of the view is giving weird results.

Comment: please give me val tag value.

Comment: @karansingh what are you doing?

Comment: I am trying ketan's answer but its not helping

Answer (score 0):

Use,

```
...

int id=200+i;
items[i].setId(id);
```

// Click event

```
 @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int pos,
                long arg3) {

            Log.d("success", String.valueOf(view.getId()));

        }
```

Edit:

You getting `16908308` instead of `200+i`, whenever we assign id as R.id.xx(its only format not exactly this one) android generate its id as positive integer. you can see it in your R file.Not sure but May be you facing this issue. whenever you create new AutoTextView it generates id like that.

Comment: well, logically speaking view.getId() should work and for the second option that you gave, it is not logically correct. I am adding my logcat results, it might give you some clarity

Comment: unfortunately, I cannot post images, but the method you mentioned is not working, see ketan's answer, it is a possiblity. and either way ketan's answer is also not solving this problem. Just look at his answer it might ring some bells

Comment: check my edit. I have seen ketan's answer. he is fetching `adapterview`'s `id` not clicked view's id.

Comment: If you want to access only flag that will be useful to your app. then you can also set integer Arraylist with in this loop instead of `setId`.like `arraylist.add(id)`. & you can fetch it like: `arraylist.get(pos)`.its just other way.

Comment: sorry, i did not get you. Please elaborate on what you are trying to suggest. Ok, from what i infer from your edit, I would like to clear this out that I am not assigning any Id in the R.id.xx path. since it is being assigned at runtime there is no point of R.id.xx here.

Comment: Please change your click event to `items[i].setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) { .....}`